# Picasa Web Albums Data API v3.0 python library

Tags: gdata, picasa, google-photos

I only found python library for version 1.0, is there an unofficial python library for version 3.0?

Or I should be using raw request for version 3 support in python?

If so, is there a wrapper for python that knows how to parse the xml responses?

Thanks!

Comment: This would be nice. Everything in the current api is not working. oAuth 1 Deprecated. Many api calls missing